# Is the expression "my very first option" correct?

Tags: phrases

If I'm planning to apply to enter a university, and I have several options, is it correct to say: "X university is my very first option" to emphasize that one specific university it is my first option among other universities?

Comment: I think if you are indicating an older university, by that I mean it was your first option and then you went to another university, you should say X university **was** my first option.

Comment: I'm going to apply to enter a university in the future, not in the past

Comment: Oh then remove the *was*, I prefer following @tkp's answer.

Comment: If you're saying future, IMO you could say X university is **going to be** my first option.

Answer (score 1):

It's not wrong, but you don't really need the "very".
You could also say that X university is your "preferred" option, or simply your "preference".

Comment: Ok but if I say that it's my first option, is that understood as my preferred option among all the options?

Comment: That's how I would interpret it. And if someone didn't see it that way, I don't think adding "very" would help. If I had to pick one of: "first option", "preferred option" or "preference", I'd go for "preference". "Preference" would be my preference, as it were. :-)